# How to connect with Socket.io once?

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I'm using socket.io. It works well, but I have a short doubt about the performance. I'm not sure that I use well the connection.

Here my **client** script (jade template language):

```
!!! 5
html
  head
    title Foo
    script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascript/socket.io.min.js')
    script(type='text/javascript')
      socket = new io.Socket('localhost', 3000);
      socket.connect();
      socket.on('message', function(data) {
      });
  body
```

This script is loaded on each page (because it's my layout page). So on each page, the socket connects to the server socket. That's my problem, I don't like this idea.

Is it possible to connect **once** the client socket to the server socket for every client's pages ?

In addition, is it possible to load **once** (per client) the `/javascript/socket.io.min.js` library ?

Thanks.

Comment: I am wondering the same question, my application has this on the main page and this main page is the wrapper for every single page on the site. So any page view/refresh will create a new socket connection to the server. Despite socket.io is designed to handle a lot of concurrent connections, I still feel there got be a better way to do this. Namuol's solution seems not convince to me. Is there any other way to do this (with transitional page url)? Also anyone suggest a way to effectively disconnect the socket? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to connect once the client socket to the server socket for every client's pages ?

Check [pjax](http://pjax.heroku.com/), I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the server stream the page data to the client (either with AJAX calls or using your socket) and replace a content `div` with the page data whenever the user clicks a link?

Instead of using `a href="my_page"`, use `a href="#my-page"`, and add click event listeners on all `a` elements that look at [`document.location.hash`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) to determine what "page" the user is trying to visit. You will also need to look at [`document.location.hash`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) when you first load the page in case the user is directly visiting a URL with `#my_page` at the end.

If you want "natural" urls to behave as expected (eg. `GET /my_page`), you can have the server respond as an AJAX call when it handles a `POST` request, but returns the full page with the main `div` contents pre-populated whenever `GET` is used.

Comment: It's not a good idea because my website respects the REST architecture and I want to keep beautiful urls ;)

Comment: This should still play nicely if you use AJAX. For instance, when I click  `a href="#my_page"`, an `onclick` handler can hit the server's `/my_page` url directly with `POST`, whose response will replace the `div` contents. However, if you were to directly visit `/my_page` with `GET`, you can return your main wrapper page with the contents already populated, so "beautiful" URLs can still work naturally.

Comment: By the way, are you using Node.js?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Node.js and Expressjs